# UIMA RUTA - Sofa mapping -in Aggregate Pipeline

Tags: uima, ruta

This is in regards to the question.

[UIMA RUTA - how to do find & replace using regular expression and groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578101/uima-ruta-how-to-do-find-replace-using-regular-expression-and-groups)

I'm trying to setup Sofa mappings as suggested. I have an aggregate AE with several AEs and trying to incorporate 2 RUTA AEs/scripts within this pipeline. Both RUTA AEs (and associated scripts) are responsible for REGEXP find and replace using a Modifier. The 2nd AE is dependent on the output of the first AE.  I had to configure the modifier's outputView of the 2nd AE, otherwise I was getting a 'Sofa data already set' exception.

In essence, I'm unable to weave the output of one as the input of the other AE.

The setup I have is similar to below,

```
_initialview --Input> (Normalizer1 RUTA AE) --Output> norm_1_out
norm_1_out --Input> (Normalizer2 RUTA AE) --Output> norm_2_out
norm_2_out --Input> (Other AE)
```

Here's the Aggregate AE code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<analysisEngineDescription xmlns="http://uima.apache.org/resourceSpecifier">
  <frameworkImplementation>org.apache.uima.java</frameworkImplementation>
  <primitive>false</primitive>
  <delegateAnalysisEngineSpecifiers>
    <delegateAnalysisEngine key="NormalizerPrepStep1">
      <import location="../../../ruta-annotators/desc/NormalizeNumbersEngine.xml"/>
    </delegateAnalysisEngine>

    <delegateAnalysisEngine key="NormalizerPrepStep2">
      <import location="../../../ruta-annotators/desc/NormalizeRangesEngine.xml"/>
    </delegateAnalysisEngine>
    <delegateAnalysisEngine key="Normalizer">
      <import location="../../../ruta-annotators/desc/NormalizerEngine.xml"/>
    </delegateAnalysisEngine>    
    <delegateAnalysisEngine key="SimpleAnnotator">
      <import location="../../../textanalyzer/desc/analysis_engine/SimpleAnnotator.xml"/>
    </delegateAnalysisEngine>
    </delegateAnalysisEngineSpecifiers>
  <analysisEngineMetaData>
    <name>RUTAAggregatePlaintextProcessor</name>
    <description>Runs the complete pipeline for annotating documents in plain text format.</description>
    <version/>
    <vendor/>
    <configurationParameters searchStrategy="language_fallback">
      <configurationParameter>
        <name>SegmentID</name>
        <description/>
        <type>String</type>
        <multiValued>false</multiValued>
        <mandatory>false</mandatory>
        <overrides>
          <parameter>SimpleAnnotator/SegmentID</parameter>
        </overrides>
      </configurationParameter>
    </configurationParameters>
    <configurationParameterSettings/>
    <flowConstraints>
      <fixedFlow>
        <node>NormalizerPrepStep1</node>
        <node>NormalizerPrepStep2</node>
        <node>Normalizer</node>
        <node>SimpleAnnotator</node>
      </fixedFlow>
    </flowConstraints>
    <typePriorities>
      <name>Ordering</name>
      <description>For subiterator</description>
      <version>1.0</version>
      <priorityList>
      </priorityList>
    </typePriorities>
    <fsIndexCollection/>
    <capabilities>
      <capability>
        <inputs/>
        <outputs/>
        <inputSofas>
          <sofaName>norm_1_out</sofaName>
        <sofaName>norm_2_out</sofaName>
          <sofaName>normalized</sofaName>
        </inputSofas>
        <languagesSupported/>
      </capability>
    </capabilities>
    <operationalProperties>
      <modifiesCas>true</modifiesCas>
      <multipleDeploymentAllowed>true</multipleDeploymentAllowed>
      <outputsNewCASes>false</outputsNewCASes>
    </operationalProperties>
  </analysisEngineMetaData>
  <resourceManagerConfiguration/>
<sofaMappings>
    <sofaMapping>
      <componentKey>SimpleAnnotator</componentKey>
      <aggregateSofaName>normalized</aggregateSofaName>
    </sofaMapping>
  <sofaMapping>
      <componentKey>NormalizerPrepStep2</componentKey>
      <aggregateSofaName>norm_1_out</aggregateSofaName>
    </sofaMapping>
    <sofaMapping>
      <componentKey>Normalizer</componentKey>
      <aggregateSofaName>norm_2_out</aggregateSofaName>
    </sofaMapping>
  </sofaMappings>
</analysisEngineDescription>
```

Few things to note,

- all three RUTA AEs (step1, step2, normalizer) uses RUTA Modifier
- the above setup throws an exception "No sofaFS with name norm_2_out
  found." - this happens after step 2.
- I have tried to switch 'norm_2_out' to 'modified' as the input sofa to
  normalizer, this seems to move the processing to the next step in the pipeline (normalizer), but that throws an exception "Data for Sofa feature
  setLocalSofaData() has already been set." at
  org.apache.uima.ruta.engine.RutaModifier.process(RutaModifier.java:107)
- I have tried with RUTA 2.2.0 (snapshot) with the same result

As I'm relatively new to both UIMA and RUTA, not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if there's a limitation that I'm running into.

BTW, I'm using RUTA 2.1.0

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide the actual/complete sofa mapping (code) of your aggregated analysis engine?

Comment: I have updated the question with full AggregateAE code

Comment: Any thoughts on this? Am I doing something wrong with the SOFA mappings?

Comment: Didn't have time yet to take a look, but I'll try later this week.

Comment: That would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that I noticed in your example is that you have to specify output sofas in your AAE. Those are all sofas that are created in the AAE, e.g, by one of its components.
Then there are sofa mappings missing. You have to connect the output views of the AEs with the input views of the other AEs. In your example, I only see the default input views.

I created a unit test, which can be applied as an example for this task.

The test is here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/ruta/trunk/ruta-core/src/test/java/org/apache/uima/ruta/engine/CascadedModifierTest.java

The resources (descriptors) used in the test are here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/uima/ruta/trunk/ruta-core/src/test/resources/org/apache/uima/ruta/engine

Mind that I deleted the absolute paths in the ruta descriptors and adapted the namespace of the imported scripts. They are now loaded by classpath for the test instead of using the absolute paths.

The test calls an aggregate analysis engine AAE.xml, which imports and maps five analysis engines:

- CWEngine.xml: simple Ruta script that replaces capitalized words. `CW{->REPLACE("CW")};` CW.ruta
- ModiferCW.xml: a normal modifier
- SWEngine.xml: simple Ruta script that replaces small-written words. `SW{->REPLACE("SW")};` SW.ruta
- ModiferSW.xml: a normal modifier
- SimpleEngine.xml: simple Ruta script that defines a new type and matches on "CW" followed by "SW". `DECLARE CwSw; ("CW" "SW"){-> CwSw};` Simple.ruta

The aggreagted analysis engines defines three views: global1 (input), global2 (output) and global3 (output). The sofa mapping of the components is the following:

global1 -> [CWEngine, ModiferCW] -> global2 -> [SWEngine, ModiferSW] -> global3-> [SimpleEngine]

Given the text `Peter is tired.` in the view global1, the aggregate analysis engine creates two new views with the view global3 containing the text `CW SW SW.` and one annotation of the type `Simple.CwSw`.

Comment: As stated in the answer, it is currently not possible. At least I do not see a way how to do it. Nevertheless, I will take care of it and I will write a new answer with the solution, if you are then still interested.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had played with the Modifier AE descriptor but paused that idea but will look into it again. Having said that, if you can think of any other ideas as to solve the problem with RUTA being part of the pipeline for pre-processing, that would be great.

Comment: The problem will be solved, but it probably not possible without changing the implementation. Thus, you would then need to use ruta 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT.

Comment: Moving to 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT should not be a problem. Looking forward for a solution. Also, wrt your comment about specifying both input and output Sofa mapping, even though I was planning to map output of one AE as Input of the other, the Eclipse desc editor does not allow to specify the same Sofa name for both Input and Output. Maybe I need to do some more reading but any pointers would be helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: That's because the descriptor for the script knows nothing about the inlined modifier and thus has no sofa capabilities. I'll post a running example when is problem is solved.

Comment: Any idea as to when this is likely to be fixed?

Comment: probably tomorrow, at least before the end of this week

Comment: Well, I was wrong. It is possible with the current versions of UIMA and UIMA Ruta. I adapted the answers and added an example. You should not need to use any different version of UIMA Ruta to get this up and running.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to get the sample to work.